# getAccessTokenAsync returns 13001

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

After successful manifest upload, I am now struggling with getting the access token using Office JS API. I have followed [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs) but without luck so far.

The error I am getting is `13001 - the user is not signed in Office`. However its clear that I am logged into Office 365 since I am running the add-in from Outlook Online.

Code:

```js
function showDialog() {
    getDataWithToken({ forceConsent: false });


    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000/PluginApp/index.html',
    { height: 80, width: 80, displayInIframe: true}, function(asyncResult) {
        // ... code
    });

    function getDataWithToken(options) {
        Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(options,
        function (result) {
            debugger;
            if (result.status === "succeeded") {
                //TODO1: Use the access token to get Microsoft Graph data.
            }
            else {
                handleClientSideErrors(result);
            }
        });
    }

    function handleClientSideErrors(result) {

        switch (result.error.code) {

            case 13001:
                getDataWithToken({ forceAddAccount: true });
                break;
        }
    }
```

print screen below:

[image]

Additional answers:

2) In my manifest file I have defined the ExecuteFunction to run the method when user clicked on addin. I am not using the taskpane since the width is too small. I would like to open a dialog to have more space to render the stuff. So therefore I cant get the info before the dialog is opened since I am getting possibly sensitive information so thats why the whole code is after opening of dialog.

3) My company uses primary Office 365 account. The setup is hybrid (on premise AD and cloud mailboxes. data is synced via DirSync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is a fix but I have pushed all checkboxes (in portal.azure.com -> Azure Active Directory -> Registrate apps -> myapp) desperately and I have got a different error now.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hmmmm. The product team reports that 13001 shouldn't ever be seen in Office Online. I'll try to confirm that.
2. It looks like you are calling getAccessTokenAsync inside a method that is primarily intended to open a dialog. Can you clarify why? You don't need to create a dialog to use the API.  You call the API from the task pane and if the user isn't signed in, Office itself will open a sign-in dialog.
3. Also, Office Online can be accessed by a user signed in with a Microsoft Account, so the fact that you are using it doesn't ensure that you are logged into an Office 365 account. Are you using an Office 365 account or a MSA account?
4. If you haven't already, take a look at: [Troubleshoot SSO in Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: Hi again Rick, I have edited my question with picture and answers to your questions. Let me know if something will be unclear or if you would like to share the whole code or prtscr the registration of app in Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks. I'm researching this now.

Comment: @pandemic requesting the access token from ExecuteFunction should not be an issue. I'd like to understand more on your hybrid setup. When you go to Outlook online on your browser using https://outlook.office.com, do you land on https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/... first (and then get redirected to your company's page for login)? I am also assuming that the DirSync is between AAD and your on premise AD?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT yes, just checked the redirection and I can confirm. About the DirSync also yes.

Comment: Got it. The flow is what I expect. I cannot reproduce this issue so far. Are you seeing this issue in multiple browsers? In addition, could you also capture a network trace when the API is called? You should see requests to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize (that include resource of your app). In addition, in the response header, there should be a "Location" header with more info about the error. It should look something like: https://outlook.office.com/owa/extSSO.aspx#error=...&error_description=... The error can tell us more on what's happening.

Comment: Tried it on opera and without luck. However I have pushed all buttons to allow all kind of rights in portal.azure.com and Ive got another error now (I will self answer my question so please comment freely if that was an actual fix) `The+application+named+api%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a3000%2fc64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668+was+not+found+in+the+tenant+named+cbede638-a3d9-459f-8f4e-24ced73b4e5e.` I will try to fix it by myself but I feel that I will need you guys once again.

Comment: ok stucked again, please join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164260/ms-office-addin I will wait

Comment: You shouldn't have push those buttons on azure side. The current error sounds like your AAD app is not part of your tenant. Which way did you give consent - was it admin consent, or use forceConsent=true in your API call in the addin? In addition to the error description, could you also send include the code. It should look like extSSO.aspx#error=interaction_required&error_description=AADSTS65001%3a+The+user+or+administrator+....  If you have the previous error, please add that in the comment too.